# Passing an array of files to the controller in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, request

I have a many different files stored in an array, how do i pass it over to the controller in laravel?

I am currently passing it in this manner from the blade file to the controller.

Blade file

```
var arrayOfFiles = [{file1},{file2},{file3}]
if (arrayOfFiles) {
  fd.append('file', arrayOfFiles);
}
```

The request in the controller contains {"File":"[object File],[object File],[object File]"}

Why isnt all the files available under one array?

Controller

```
if($request->file)
 {
   foreach ($request->file as $file) {
     error_log(json_encode($file));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$all_files = $request->allFiles();
foreach ($all_files['file'] as $file) {
    // do something with $file here...
}
```